# Regex: Matching and extracting float number

Tags: regex, grep

When I use grep to extract from status file using:

```
grep -ioP "vsim_nvclk_per_second.* " status
```

Output:

```
vsim_nvclk_per_second:float:27.2237552420673 |
vsim_post_munge_elapsed_s:float:16.1 |
```

But I just need

```
27.2237552420673
```

How do I change my regex ?

Comment: Add content of file `status` to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
grep -ioP 'vsim_nvclk_per_second\D*\K\d[\d.]*' status
```

The `vsim_nvclk_per_second\D*\K\d[\d.]*` PCRE pattern (PCRE syntax is enabled with `P` option) matches

- `vsim_nvclk_per_second` - a literal string
- `\D*` - any zer or more non-digit chars
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `\d[\d.]*` - a digit and then any zero or more digits or dots.

See a [PCRE regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/m4mk2S/1).

Comment: I've used the look behind and lookahead options `grep -Po '(?<=vsim_nvclk_per_second:float:).*(?=\s\|)'`  status

Comment: @SergioAraujo This is not clear if you can rely on `:float:` after `vsim_nvclk_per_second`, it is not stated in the question that `:float:` is a hardcoded value.

Comment: Maybe adding `.*:` because it is a greedy regex that will match until the last `:` could solve the problem.